# How to perform a GraphQL mutation in ExpressJS with a dynamic value sent from React frontend when building a Shopify App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, graphql, shopify-api-node

When I call a simple query from React, the below code with hardcoded values for 123 and NEW NAME work fine.

REACT

```
    const data = useAppQuery({
        url: "/api/collection",
        reactQueryOptions: {
            onSuccess: () => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            },
        },
    });
```

EXPRESS

```
app.get("/api/collection", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const session = res.locals.shopify.session;
        const client = new shopify.api.clients.Graphql({ session });

        const response = await client.query({
            data: `mutation updateCollectionHandle {
        collectionUpdate(input: {id: "gid://shopify/Collection/123", title: "NEW NAME"}) {
          collection {
            title
          }
          userErrors {
            field
            message
          }
        }
      }`,
    });
        res.status(200).send(response);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});
```

But how do I make a mutation and have the **123** and **NEW NAME** as dynamic values received from React? Using REST API I simply would add them in to a data field, but with GraphQL in Shopify I don't understand how to pass the values with the `useAppQuery` function as it doesn't accept the data parameters.

Comment: You can use variables in your GraphQL document and then assign variable values dynamically. I'm not sure how your GraphQL client handles variables though.

Comment: The problem is really sending them from React to Express application. I have used `useAuthenticatedFetch()` provided by Shopify and the one in my example `useAppQuery`, but both are basically just GET methods. I need to send some data from React app with the query.